# Decoding JSON with same named repeating coding keys in Swift

Tags: json, swift

I need to decode JSON that has multiple keys named the same.  The JSON looks like this:

```
[{"errors":[{"extensions":{"code":"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR","reason":"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"},"message":"Unexpected error occurred"}]},{"data":{"createCsrfToken":{"__typename":"CreateCsrfTokenResponse","csrfToken":"frcxsr60fG4nLnW9HuZXDDYUEgiekGryHDa1104dPwnBz8xyhaQtx2WiVcS6pbDoCUOl9S3Q9kxkh0TSJ1LwecquzgIPGGWRu6s0qTVIHDTjdSweCSgBx5gF1kID4LNurUSEKD","appSessionToken":"eJX7jjUuaZccJ4dzLjFXhNYPm60k0SKrOS7jaA1lkWmA10bpfeLjOSCARpSnm8R3xTi4ImC487aQi4kasjEKPJpBYwnzd394Y6NN1U4g5GkQi5TUHo3691fLXLnSEevd"}}},{"errors":[{"extensions":{"code":"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR","reason":"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"},"message":"Unexpected error occurred"}]}]
```

Notice the two keys named errors.

This is the JSONDecoder statement:

```
let csrfData: [CsrfData] = try JSONDecoder().decode([CsrfData].self, from: uData)
```

These are the structures I'm using.

```
struct CsrfExtensions: Decodable {
    let code: String
    let reason: String
}

struct CsrfErrorsArray: Decodable {
    let extensions: CsrfExtensions
//    let message: String
}

struct CsrfToken: Decodable {
    let __typename: String
    let csrfToken: String
    let appSessionToken: String
}

struct CreateCsrfToken: Decodable {
    let createCsrfToken: CsrfToken
}

struct CsrfData: Decodable {
//    let errors: [CsrfErrorsArray]
    let data: CreateCsrfToken
}
```

I had commented out errors hoping to just skip that completely.  So my error may not be related to the multiple errors keys at all.

This is the error I receive:

keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil) ("data").", underlyingError: nil))

1. What is causing the decode to fail?
2. How do you decode JSON with multiple same name keys in Swift?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This JSON doesn't have two `errors` keys. It is an array of objects, and two of those objects each have an `errors` key, so that's not causing any problem for the decoder. Your problem is that there are two different types of object in this array (`data` objects and `error` objects). When you try to decode the first item, there is no `data` key (which your struct requires), and it fails.

There are many discussions of decoding arrays with different elements ("heterogeneous arrays") on Stack Overflow. One is [Decode heterogeneous array JSON using Swift decodable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62583068/decode-heterogeneous-array-json-using-swift-decodable)